# Store data from struct in lists of variable size in C

Tags: c, struct

I want to use MPI in my project. In order to send my data to another processor, I first have to store particle data in a list.

[image: Five lists of different size]

These lists can have variable size. So basically I want to save the data of this struct:

```
typedef struct {
        double    x[DIM];
        double    v[DIM];
        double    a[DIM];
        double    m;
} Particle;
```

into this list 'plist'. Additionally I want to save the size of the list in `plistSize`:

```
typedef struct{
    double **plist;
    int plistSize;
} ParticleList;
```

I am still a newbie in C so this task is somehow difficult to me.

So far I did the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 2

typedef struct{
    double **plist;
    int plistSize;
} ParticleList;

typedef struct {
        double                x[DIM];
        double                v[DIM];
        double                a[DIM];
        double                 m;
} Particle;

void sendPar(int *n, int npr, Particle *p){

    // Allocate memory for ParticleList
    ParticleList *pl = malloc(sizeof(pl)*npr);

    // Allocate memory for plistSize -> Does not work
    //for(int k=0; k<npr; k++){
    //    pl->plistSize[k] = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    //}

    // Allocate memory for every list
    for(int k=0; k<npr; k++){
        pl->plist[k] = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n[k]);
    }

    // Write data into list.
    for(int k=0; k<npr; k++){
        for(int l=0; l<n[k]; l++){
            int i = 0;
            for(int d=0; d<DIM; d++){
                pl->plist[k][i] = p[k].x[d];
                i++;
            }
            for(int d=0; d<DIM; d++){
                pl->plist[k][i] = p[k].v[d];
                i++;
            }
            for(int d=0; d<DIM; d++){
                pl->plist[k][i] = p[k].a[d];
                i++;
            }
            pl->plist[k][i] = p[k].m;
        }
   // pl->plistSize[k] = n[k];
    }

    // Free memory
    free(pl);
}

int main(){
    // Number of processors
    int npr = 3;

    // Number of particles
    int np = 3;

    // Allocate memory for particles
    Particle *p = malloc(sizeof(p)*np);
    for(int k=0; k<np; k++){
        for(int d=0; d<DIM; d++){
            p[k].x[d] = 1000*k+100*d;
            p[k].v[d] = 10000*k+1000*d;
            p[k].a[d] = 10*k+d;
        }
        p[k].m = 100000+k;
    }

    // Size of lists, in this case every list has same length
    int n[npr];
    n[0] = 10;
    n[1] = 10;
    n[2] = 10;

    sendPar(n, npr, p);

    // Free memory
    free(p);
}
```

I get an seg fault error. Probably I did something wrong here:

```
// Allocate memory for ParticleList
ParticleList *pl = malloc(sizeof(pl)*npr);

// Allocate memory for every list
for(int k=0; k<npr; k++){
    pl->plist[k] = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n[k]);
}
```

Additionally I am not able to allocate memory for `plistSize`. I get the error `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`. Does someone see why?

Comment: `double **plist;` -> `Particle **plist;` also `ParticleList *pl = malloc(sizeof(pl)*npr);` -> `ParticleList *pl = malloc(sizeof(ParticleList)*npr);`

Comment: @Magisch What do you mean with `double **plist;` -> `Particle **plist;`. `Particle` has no such type as `plist`. Can you please explain what you think is wrong?

Comment: You type your `plist` as type double (an array of many doubles) when in reality it needs to be an array of many `Particle` structs

Comment: @Magisch Ok, I see your point. But what I want to do is to save particle data from `Particle` in long lists which I need in order to send the data to other processors. The list of one particle will then look like : `[x[0],x[1],x[2],v[0],v[1],v[2],a[0],a[1],a[2],m]`.

Comment: Well this complicates things. You know what `pl->plist[k][i]` actually does, right? It's the same as `pl->plist[k*i]`. Thats one problem. You're overwriting your pointer with data. Second problem is by doing `ParticleList *pl = malloc(sizeof(pl)*npr);` you allocate enough memory to hold `npr` pointers to `ParticleList`s, not what you want either

Comment: Assuming `npr` correlates to the number of entries (doubles) in your `plist`, you should be doing something like `ParticleList *pl = malloc(sizeof(Double*)*npr);`

Comment: How does that picture relate to your structure?

Comment: @Lundin The picture represents `plist`s of differnt size.

Comment: @Magisch What would be the correct way even to have a structure which holds lists of different size and the size of the list?

Comment: @Samuel I'd say allocate a chunk of memory (enough to hold all contents of the list) to the list itself and then read data into it like you currently do. You don't have to have many individually allocated lists, just imagine them (and access them as needed)